# Is regularity needed for uniqueness of Haar measure on compact groups?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

I've looking at the following proof of the uniqueness of Haar measure on compact groups. I think I understand every step in the proof but I don't see where regularity is used. I see that the both fact that the measures are translation invariant and that $H(G)=1=H'(G)$ (in particular to guarantee that Fubini's theorem holds) are used extensively, but regularity doesn't seem to be necessary for uniqueness. Is this the case or am I missing something?

Let $H'$ be a measure with the same properties as $H$ and let $f\in C(G)$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int f(y)dH'(y)&=\int H(G)f(y)dH'(y)=\int(\int f(y)dH'(y))dH(y)\\
&=\int(\int f(xy)dH'(y))dH(x)=\int(\int f(xy)dH(x))dH'(y)\\
&=\int(\int f(x)dH(x))dH'(y)=\int H(G)f(x)dH(x)=\int fdH(x)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Therefore, $H'=H$.

By the way, to show uniqueness shouldn't it be enough to show that the above equalities hold for indicator functions? From a set theoretic perspective it should be enough since two functions are defined to be equal if they are equal pointwise.

PS: I'm sorry about the notation I used. I realize it's not the best but it's the one I've been using.

Comment: @Eric: It's not so clear to me that Fubini's theorem really applies. For that, you would need to know that $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ is measurable with respect to the product sigma algebra of the Borel sigma algebra, which is in general strictly smaller than the Borel sigma algebra on the product. I once had exactly the same question that you have, and discovered a solution in a quite old paper by Japanese guys who published either in German or in a German journal. I will try to dig out the reference.

Comment: @PhoemueX I would really appreciate if you could dig out the paper where you found the solution to my question. I can't read German, though, so unless the argument is purely symbolic I don't know if I'll be able to follow it.

Comment: @PhoemueX I thought that the product σ-algebra of Borel σ-algebras was in fact equal to the Borel σ-algebra on the product. At least I know it holds in Euclidean space. I remember we went over the proof in my measure theory course. On the other hand equality does fail if you replace 'Borel' with 'Lebesgue'. Your point remains valid nontheless, it's not so clear that the theorem applies. I should also mention that the function $f$ considered is continuous.

Comment: I found the paper (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195572875). It is indeed by two Japanese guys written in German :) If I have time (hopefully on the weekend), I will translate the important part of the argument. Regarding the Fubini theorem: I think it should be applicable since your function is continuous; the details should be in the book "Abstract Harmonic Analysis" by Folland. If you assume the function to be continuous, however, this will only show that $\int f \, dH = \int f \, d H'$ for all continuous $f$, which only yields $H = H'$ if both measures are regular.

Comment: Finally: If your group is also metrizable, then *any* finite measure on $G$ will be regular, so that there is nothing to show. The interesting case is really only if the group is compact, but not separable, as considered in the paper that I linked.

Comment: Ok, found the reference I was looking for regarding Fubini's theorem. Its in Follands "Real Analysis". He first shows in Theorem 7.20 that the product $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel sigma algebras is contained in the Borel sigma algebra of the product, but you can have a strict inclusion. Nevertheless, he then shows in Proposition 7.22 that every $C_c$ function (continuous with compact support, where the support condition is trivial in your case) is measurable with respect to the product of the Borel sigma algebras.